# Query without ORDER BY slower?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, innodb

I'm executing the following on my INNODB database

QUERY WITHOUT ORDER BY

```
SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE second_designer
    FROM  itemrow FORCE INDEX(second_designer)
    WHERE  category like '%'
      and  type like '%'
      and  availability like '%'
    GROUP BY  second_designer

259 results in 0.0286 seconds.
```

QUERY WITH ORDER BY DESC

```
SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE second_designer
    FROM  itemrow FORCE INDEX(second_designer)
    WHERE  category like '%'
      and  type like '%'
      and  availability like '%'
    GROUP BY  second_designer
    ORDER BY  second_designer DESC 

259 results in 0.0008 seconds.
```

INDEX

```
ADD INDEX `second_designer` (`second_designer ` , `availability`,
                             `category`, `type`) USING BTREE
```

EXPLAIN

```
id select_type table   type  possible_keys   key         key_len ref  rows Extra
1  SIMPLE      itemrow index second_designer second_designer 608 NULL 44521 Using where; Using index
```

Why is the query with order by clause so much faster than the one without?

Comment: This question is quite meaningless, the index you have cannot be used in the WHERE clause in either query. You have given the explain only for one query.

Comment: The explain is the same for both queries. Also isn't the explain telling that the index 'second_designer' is being used?

Comment: that's only for the group by if you posted the indented explain output that would be clearer

Comment: Didn't know this, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE itemrow `.

Comment: Did you run each query twice to avoid caching effects in the buffer_pool?  (I am not talking about the Query cache; thanks for avoiding it.)

Comment: The `GROUP BY` should have used the index, plus the index is "covering".  Still, it needed to scan about 44K rows, so 0.8ms seems impossible.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for both.  This may give some more clues.

Comment: @RickJames thanks for your comments! I was about to add the `SHOW CREATE` results to the original question when I noticed something weird. All queries are made from within a phpmyadmin interface.Phpmyadmin adds a default `LIMIT 0, 30` to all queries, when I remove this limit both queries perform the same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference was caused by the 'hidden' `LIMIT` phpMyAdmin adds to all queries.

[$cfg['MaxRows'] Listed in phpMyAdmin Docs](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?highlight=maxrows#cfg_MaxRows)

After setting a `LIMIT` explicitly the queries both perform the same (259 results in 0.0286 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

when we use order by it uses indexes to sort result rows. in your query without order by index are not used. that is the difference query running faster with order by